# Why are endline characters illegal in HTML string sent over ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Within HTML, it is okay to have endline characters. But when I try to send HTML strings that have endline characters over AJAX to have them operated with JavaScript/jQuery, it returns an error that says that endline characters are illegal. For example, if I have a Ruby string:

```
"<div>Hello</div>"
```

and jsonify it with Ruby by `to_json`, and send it over ajax, parse it within JavaScript by `JSON.parse`, and insert that in jQuery like:

```
$('body').append('<div>Hello</div>');
```

then it does not return an error, but if I do a similar thing with a string like

```
"<div>Hello\n</div>"
```

it returns an error. Why are they legal in HTML and illegal in AJAX? Are there any other differences between a legal HTML string loaded as a page and legal HTML string sent over ajax?

Comment: What is giving you an error? There is no legal/illegal for whatever you decide to send to your server -- you're running into a problem somewhere along the line, either in building the request or parsing the response.

Comment: There's probably an error in your code - show us some.

Comment: are you sending that string as a JSON string? (which would be invalid JSON in theory, but often not in practice)

Comment: @WalterTross Yes. And then I parse is back.

Comment: ok, then your problem is JSON, not HTML nor AJAX. Just replace your newlines with `\n` (and don't forget to escape double quotes and backslashes)

Comment: Sorry if my terminology was inaccurate, but by newlines, I meant `\n`. And they are json escaped. If I delete the `\n` from the string, it works. The presence or the absence of `\n` is the only difference.

Comment: Strings containing literal line breaks can break JavaScript code.

Comment: you must have an extra decoding down the line, which could be solved by an extra encoding, but that is not the proper solution. The example you give is too simplified, because you are not really using a literal string (which of course would work). You should probably provide more detail, including the error message

Comment: @MonTyAdel I know that. I guessed that is the case. That is the whole point of my question. My question is asking for detail on that. Can you elaborate?

Comment: are you sure that your JSON really contains a backslash character followed by an `n` character where a newline should be?

Comment: @WalterTross It is a newline within a Ruby string that I see as a real line break on my editor. I apply the Ruby method `to_json` to it.

Comment: If I were you, I would from a *x shell do a curl call to get that JSON, pipe it into od -tx1z and check that all is properly quoted and escaped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

string literals can contain line breaks, they just need to be escaped with a backslash like so:

```
var string = "hello\
world!";
```

However, this does not create a line break in the string, as it must be an explicit \n escape sequence. This would technically become helloworld. Doing

```
var string = "hello"
+ "world"
```

would be much cleaner

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Escaping_characters

Comment: I don't see how this would apply, because Ruby's `to_json` is used to do the escaping, so that shouldn't have anything to do with line breaks in string literals.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the type of the ajax call as 'html'.  Jquery will try to infer the type when parsing the response.

If the response is json, newlines should be escaped.

I'd recommend using a library to serialize json.  You're unlikely to handle all the edge cases if you roll your own.

Comment: Sometime, it is not purely an html string. It can be a chunk of JavaScript code, so I cannot do that.

Comment: After trial and error, I now know that newlines need to be escaped. I am asking why, and what other things I need to be careful of.

Comment: what language are you using server side?  I've had success using a json serialize library from json.org. also, apache has some nice escape libraries in java

Answer (score 1):

Seeing how you're already escaping the JSON properly by using `to_json` in Ruby, I do believe the bug is in jQuery; when there are newlines in the string it has trouble determining whether you meant to create a single element or a document fragment. This would work just fine:

```
var str = "<div>Hello\n</div>";

var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = str;

$('body').append(wrapper);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/ofokoh/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Strings in JavaScript MUST appear on a single line, with the exception of escaping that line:

```
var str = "abc \
def";
```

However note that the newline is escaped and will not appear in the string itself.

The best option is `\n`, but note that if it is already going through something that parses `\n` then you will need to double-escape it as `\\n`.